# Format UITableView cell text font based on query

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

The UITableView Cell below alternates text location according to the search type. The Text label is set to Standard and detail text is currently set to Italic. I want this to be the reverse.

i.e. if genusSpecies : animal.commonName then textLabel = ItalicFont else if animal.commonName : genusSpecies then textLabel = StandardFont

I'd like to apply this rule to the code below.

```
- (void)setAnimal:(ITanimal *)animal forType:(ITSectionType)type {
    _animal = animal;

    BOOL isCommonType = (type == ITSectionTypeCommonName);
    NSString *genusSpecies = animal.species];

    [self.textLabel setFont:ItalicFont];
    [self.textLabel setText:(!isCommonType)? genusSpecies : animal.commonName];

    [self.detailTextLabel setFont:StandardFont];
    [self.detailTextLabel setText:(!isCommonType)? animal.commonName : genusSpecies];

}
```

Comment: What is the question? Just add the same type of conditional expression to the font setting that you have for the label text setting and you're done. It's ugly but works.

Comment: I have adjusted the question above to make it clearer.

Comment: What does `if genusSpecies : animal.commonName ...` mean? I'm pretty sure there is no `:` operator for these kind of expressions. Isn't it == by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a little vague but my feeling is that you have almost everything in place. Just create a BOOL that you can use to decide if you are showing a genus species. Like this:

```
BOOL isGenuSpecies = (boolean expression to decide if this is a genus species)

UIFont *textLabelFont = isGenusSpecies? StandardFont : ItalicFont;
UIFont *detailTextLabelFont = isGenusSpecies? ItalicFont : StandardFont;

[self.textLabel setFont: textLabelFont];

[self.detailTextLabel setFont: detailTextLabelFont];
```

This works provided that you have `StandardFont` and `ItalicFont` defined somehere previously.

Answer (score 0):

For italic font you can use

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Oblique" size:13.0]
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question I was asking. I was asking a condition, the font style has already been set.